# Is it good practice to depend on python's with...as statement

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I'm curious if it is considered safe or good practice to depend on python's with...as statement. For example when opening a file:

```
with open("myfile","w") as myFile:
    #do something
```

So in this example I neglected to explicitly call `myFile.close()` however I can assume it was called when python exited the `with...as` statement by calling the objects `__exit__()` method. Is it good practice/safe to depend upon this or would it be better to always explicitly call `file.close()`

Comment: Are you aware your example code tried to read from a file that was opened for writing?

Comment: Oops, just wrote a quick example, fixed it now.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what context managers are *for*, to rely on *them* to close the file for you. Context managers are called even if there was an exception.

The alternative is to use an `finally` block instead:

```
myFile = open("myfile","w")
try:
    # do something with myFile
finally:
    myFile.close()
```

but because the block inside of the `try:` might be long, by the time you get to the `finally` statement you have forgotten what you were setting this up for.

Context managers are more powerful still. Because the `__exit__` method is informed of any exceptions, they can act as exception handlers as well (ignore the exception, raise another, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `with` statement is better way. Since Python 2.5, the file object has been equipped with `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods. The `__exit__()` method closes the file object.

Python guarantees that it will call the `__exit__()` method, but there is not guarantee that the `__exit__()` method will close the resource, especially with 3rd party code. You need to manually verify that.