# Python read/write file without closing

Tags: python, file

Sometimes when I open a file for reading or writing in Python

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')
```

or

```
f = open('workfile', 'w')
```

I read/write the file, and then at the end I forget to do `f.close()`. Is there a way to automatically close after all the reading/writing is done, or after the code finishes processing?

Comment: What version of Python do you have?  You probably want to use `with ... as` syntax.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.5. Is it compatible with that syntax?

Comment: Yes, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776853/python-with-as) answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    #file is opened and accessible via f 
    pass
#file will be closed before here
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use the **with...as** statement

```
with open('workfile') as f:
    """Do something with file"""
```

or you could also use a **try...finally block**

```
f = open('workfile', 'r')
try:
    """Do something with file"""
finally:
    f.close()
```

Although since you say that you forget to add f.close(), I guess the with...as statement will be the best for you and given it's simplicity, it's hard to see the reason for not using it!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do with your file, after you read it in, this is how you should read and write it back:

$ python myscript.py sample.txt sample1.txt

Then the first argument (sample.txt) is our "oldfile" and the second argument (sample1.txt) is our "newfile". You can then do the following code into a file called "myscript.py"

```
    from sys import argv
    script_name,oldfile,newfile = argv
    content = open(oldfile,"r").read()
    # now, you can rearrange your content here
    t = open(newfile,"w")
    t.write(content)
    t.close()
```

Comment: It is a bad habit not to use context-management (or try/finally) constructs to ensure resources are always closed. If this code gets transformed into a function, it will leak file-descriptors on any error.